# What effects do parentheses have on the 'or' operator in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a difference between these two statements in python:

```
if tag == ('/event' or '/organization' or '/business'):
```

and

```
if tag == '/event' or '/organization' or '/business':
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are both wrong. What you need is:

```
if tag == '/event' or tag == '/organization' or tag == '/business':
```

or:

```
if tag in ['/event', '/organization', '/business']:
```

Comment: Replace that list with a tuple.

Comment: @nightcracker: I disagree. To me, tuples indicate ordering.

Comment: A list and a tuple are __exactly__ the same with the mere difference that a list is mutable (it can change) and a tuple is immutable (it can't change). Both in performance and morale a tuple is fit here.

Comment: @nightcracker: There is no performance difference according to my testing. And I have no idea what you mean by "morale". As Kirk says, tuples are normally used for ordered fixed-length sequences where an item's position dictates its role (e.g. a 3D vector). Lists are normally used for a sequence of homogenous data, which is a closer fit here.

Comment: @interjay: Talking about performance a tuple take less memory than a list, and in my common sense i use tuple when i want my data to be immutable else i use list. but if the performance is really an issue (which is not in this example :) ) we should use a __set__ don't we :)

Comment: @singularity: I wouldn't be surprised if a set was slower than a list/tuple for only 3 elements. In any case, this entire discussion is pointless. If such a micro-optimization is important to you, you shouldn't be using Python in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

The proper solution is

```
if tag in ('/event', '/organization', '/business'):
```

It not only uses the `in` operator which is perfect for this purpose but also uses a tuple (immutable) so the python interpreter can optimize it better than a (mutable) list.

Benchmark showing that tuples are faster than lists:

```
In [1]: import timeit
In [2]: t1 = timeit.Timer('"b" in ("a", "b", "c")')
In [3]: t2 = timeit.Timer('"b" in ["a", "b", "c"]')

In [4]: t1.timeit(number=10000000)
Out[4]: 0.7639172077178955

In [5]: t2.timeit(number=10000000)
Out[5]: 2.240161895751953
```

Comment: @interjay, here is a small test I ran (seems using tuple is faster)
>>> timeit.timeit('a=9;x=(1,2,3,4,5);a in x') 
0.23711281741111634
>>> timeit.timeit('a=9;x=[1,2,3,4,5];a in x') 
0.4927707292406467

Comment: I would say that since 3.2 the faster way is x in {1, 2, 3} see http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations

Comment: I ran the same test as you, and actually got faster results for the list: `>>> t1 = timeit.Timer('"b" in ("a", "b", "c")')
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer('"b" in ["a", "b", "c"]')
>>> t1.timeit(number=10000000)
0.814497625565931
>>> t2.timeit(number=10000000)
0.6891633619835877`

Comment: The times are nearly identical when isolating the speed of `in` against tuples and lists: `>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("'b' in foo", setup="foo = ('a', 'b', 'c')")
>>> t1.timeit(number=10000000)
0.4698009490966797
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer("'b' in foo", setup="foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']")
>>> t2.timeit(number=10000000)
0.46918296813964844`

Answer (score 3):

I don't either will work the way you want it to.  What you would want is:

```
if tag in ['/event', '/organization', '/business']:
```

Answer (score 2):

The first is identical to `if tag == 'event'`. The second is identical to `if tag == '/event' or True or True`, which is always True.

Answer (score 1):

`('/event' or '/organization' or '/business')` is evaluated to `'/event'`, thus first thing is equivalent to `if tag == '/event':`

`tag == '/event' or '/organization' or '/business'` is equivalent to `(tag == '/event') or '/organization'`.

What you actually want is:

```
if tag in ('/event', '/organization', '/business'):
```